# The use of the singular form of the verb, "set"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, tense, headlinese

I'm trying to learn the correct use of the singular form of the verb "set" which is obviously "sets".

Pls note, I need it for the practical application of constructing news headlines and not for other purposes.

Which of these sentences is correct:

- Comedienne Kiki **set** to welcome her first child.
- Comedienne Kiki **sets** to welcome her first child.

Bearing in mind that it's best to express the news headlines in this case in simple present tense.

Also note that I have intentionally avoided the use of the verb "is" in the two expressions, so do not chip them back in.

Please feel free to use other sentences detailing the use of 'sets' to drive home your argument. (Without incorporating the verb "is" in the expression).

Thank you!

Comment: The full form (non-"headlinese") of that sentence is: "*Comedienne Kiki **is** set to welcome her first child.*" The word "set" here is an adjective, not a verb at all. Does that help you answer your own question?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I still have some grey areas though. Could you help me with some other expressions using the verb "sets" pls?

Comment: Also, why do you think news blogs and websites do not want to use the verb "is"?

Comment: If you have a specific question about "set", feel free to ask a new question. Unlike other websites, we don't chat back and forth here. This site is just for clear questions and verifiable answers. The comment sections are just for clarification. As for not using "is", look up "headlinese". It's a writing style for headlines that lets fewer words say more, which is what you want in a headline.